# Update html data table if database changed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a user table in my panel using following `Php` code :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="order_table">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        Include_once("db/connection.php");
        $stmt_select_users = $conn->prepare("SELECT name,mobile FROM api_user order by create_date DESC limit 5;");
        $stmt_select_users->execute();
        while ($row_select_users = $stmt_select_users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_select_users['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_select_users['mobile']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know about following function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(function () {
       $("#order_table").load("users_table.php")
   }, 3000);
});
```

***but I don't want to update the full table, Just if a row inserted, table add that row.*** Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a PHP file that returns only the records you want and manipulate the table with javascript.

Assuming you have that script that returns the HTML table row element like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Some value</td>
    <td>Another value</td>
</tr>
```

You can do something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.get("my-script.php", function(data) {
            $("#order_table table").append(data);
        });
   }, 3000);
});
```

For more information http://api.jquery.com/append/ and https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

I hope I could help.

**EDIT: Code example**

Disclaimer: This is a really simple code snippet and you should perform validations and optimizations.

```
<?php
// request.php
$data = [
    ['valor 1 - linha 1', 'valor 2 - linha 1'],
    ['valor 1 - linha 2', 'valor 2 - linha 2'],
    ['valor 1 - linha 3', 'valor 2 - linha 3'],
];

$afterIndex = $_GET['afterIndex'];
$count = sizeof($data);

$tableRows = [];
if ($afterIndex < $count)  {
    for ($i = $afterIndex; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $item = $data[$i];
        $tableRows[] = '<tr><td>' .$item[0] . '</td><td>' . $item[1] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}

echo json_encode([
    'index' => $count, 
    'rows' => $tableRows
]);
```

The data array is a simulation of your database, modify the code to your needs.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var index = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            $.get("/request.php?afterIndex="+index, function(data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                index = response.index;
                for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
                    $("#order_table table tbody").append(response.rows[i]);
                }
            });
    }, 3000);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

The script above makes a request to the php code and render the response rows in the table.

The table is something like:

```
<div id="order_table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help me more